# for abc in cursor: NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined (data migration)

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mongodb, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate my data from MongoDB to Mysql and my data has more than 1M records.
I've used Studio 3T for this but it limits the records to 1000 records (well we don't have the budget to buy the premium version). Hence, I'm trying to use python following this post: "http://www.youngdba.com/2017/03/migrating-mongodb-data-to-mysql-using.html".

Everything went smoothly until the last part which the python shell returns the error:

```
cursor1= db.cursor()
 i=1
 for abc in cursor:
    uids=int(abc.get("uids"))
    fnames=abc.get("first_name")
    sql= "insert into client_test(uid,first_name) values"+'('+str(uids)+",'"+fnames+"')"
    print ("Inserted"+str(i)+" record")
    i+=1
    Number_of_rows=cursor1.execute(sql)
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in 
for abc in cursor:
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined**

Why is the code not working? Am I missing something here?
Please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe you should use `cursor1` instead of `for abc in cursor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop should be:

```py
for abc in cursor1:
```

There's no variable named cursor, only cursor1. You are missing the 1 from the variable name.

Comment: did what you said. However, it returns another error:
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    for abc in cursor1:
  File "C:\Users\dk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 406, in __iter__
    self._check_executed()
  File "C:\Users\dk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 126, in _check_executed
    raise ProgrammingError("execute() first")
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: execute() first**

Does this mean the code is incorrect in the 1st place?

Comment: This new error is out of the scope of this post. Create another one with more details, maybe explain what modules you are using exactly, etc. The answer to the issue in this post is above, so mark it as answered and comment the link of your new post here and I will do my best to help with this other error.

Comment: I will do that. Thank you and have a good day sir!